# php with postgresql database

Tags: php, postgresql

i wanna to connect to postgresql database using php but it display a blank screen when submit and doesnt execute the query

Thanks in advance

Update: this is my code

```
function execute_query($dbName,$query){ 
  $host = "localhost"; 
  $user = "postgres"; 
  $pass = ""; 
  $db = "test"; 
  echo "before create connection"; 
  $con = pg_connect ("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass"); 
  echo "After connection is created"; 
  if (!$con) { 
    echo "not connected"; 
//   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  } 
  $result = pg_query($con, $query); 
  pg_close($con); 
  return $result; 
}
```

The output: 
display the message "before connection" but doesn't display the message "After connection is created" or "not connected".

Comment: You really need to flesh out the question if you expect a reasonable answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not enough information. Please look at the php and/or apache log for errors or perhaps turn on display for errors in php.ini.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is likely a PHP error that’s getting recorded to a log file somewhere. Locate the log file, or enable showing the log errors on your page by using the following at the top of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

This is a short-term solution and can’t be used in deployment (where you want to set `display_errors` to `0`). For a long-term solution, you really want to locate the Apache or PHP error log and `tail` it.

To try to find the error log, run the following script:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

In the Configuration > PHP Core section, look for `error_log`. If that’s not set, you can set it in your `php.ini` file. All errors will be recorded to that file, even if you have `display_errors` set to `0`.

Comment: i used the previous script and it works. but it display the error
"Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()".

Thanks for ur help

Comment: It sounds like PostgreSQL support is not installed. Use the `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` script and verify that there is a section titled **pgsql**, which is the PHP module that includes the `pg_connect()` function. You may also want to look for a section titled **pdo_pgsql**, which is a more modern interface for PostgreSQL. If pdo_pgsql is present, you could use the `PDO()` constructor and related functions instead of `pg_connect()`.

Answer (score 2):

Add a php file to your server and put this in that file:

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

When you open that file from the browser, check if postgres support is setup for php.
you should something like this on the page:

```
pgsql

PostgreSQL Support  enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   8.2.3
Multibyte character support enabled
SSL support disabled
Active Persistent Links 0
Active Links    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your web server's error log (for instance, /var/log/apache2/error.log is a common location for the Apache2 log) and see if there is an error reported from PHP there.

Comment: there is no apache folder in the path /var/log/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the php error reporting level in your ini file if this is a local development server.

Comment: that is my code
function execute_query($dbName,$query){

 $host = "localhost";
 $user = "postgres";
 $pass = "";
 $db = "test";
 echo "before create connection";
 $con = pg_connect ("host=$host dbname=$db user=$user password=$pass"); 
 echo "After connection is created";
 if (!$con)
 {
  echo "not connected";
  // die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 $result = pg_query($con, $query);
 pg_close($con);
 return $result;
}

The output: display the message "before connection" but doesn't display the message "After connection is created" or "not connected".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that your php does not have postgresql support, cf. http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.pgsql.php:

> Note: Not all functions are supported
>   by all builds. It depends on your
>   libpq (The PostgreSQL C client
>   library) version and how libpq is
>   compiled. If PHP PostgreSQL extensions
>   are missing, then it is because your
>   libpq version does not support them.

Comment: the postgresSql plus installed into my machine and the same error is appeared. i dont know why??

Comment: What kind of machine do you use? Windows / Linux / Mac? If Linux, what distribution? Have you installed all dependencies for using PHP with Postgresql, especially the right version of libpq?