# How to connect to a remote DB from my computer with PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I am quite new in PHP and databases. I am trying to connect to a remote Postgres database from my computer. In the past I have done this by using a localhost and a MySQL database but it is the first time that I try to connect in another host.
This is the PHP code that I have:

```
  <?php
  $conn_string = "host=hostname.com port=xxxx dbname=dbname user=root password=root";

  $dbconn = pg_connect($conn_string);
  ?>
```

I read several articles in internet saying that it is enough to change the hostname from localhost to the one provided but it doesn't seem to work. I also have deactivated my firewall in case there is some problem with the communication but with no success.

As I said I am quite new with this and in the past I had used only test servers (localhost). Back then I was using software like Wamp and Mamp and I was placing the script files in the localhost.

So, my questions are:
1)  where should I save the test.php file which has the above lines of code?
2) Would this solve the problem or I am missing some important concept here?

I hope what I am trying to say is clear. Please let me know if I have to be more specific in something.

Thanks
Dimtiris

Comment: Is this code not working?

Comment: This may help in case.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322351/php-with-postgresql-database

Comment: are you connecting to db on another server? you may need to configure that server to accept incoming connections from another ip

Comment: It sounds silly but the problem is that I don't know where I should place the test.php file which contains this code!

Comment: Should it be that if I run the code with a browser then it should connect?

Comment: Hope so your hostname is ok!Always use the hostname instead of IP as the hostname will be converted to an IP address behind the scenes for you. No need to do it yourself. Plus, hardcoding IPs is bad practice as they can change over time.

Comment: host=hostname.com .....there should be the ip from the remote server ;)

Comment: @ Robert Rozas: I have the ip in the host. I just put some random values in order to display the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, error messages would really help.  Based on the comments I will say I suspect that you are connecting to the right server.  However you are using a username of "root?"  It would be highly unusual for such a username to be present on Postgres.

The first one is where to put the file.  This should be put in your web server's document root or cgi bin depending on how you have things configured (probably the former).

For your second question, please double check usernames and passwords, and make sure you can use those usernames and passwords via pgAdmin III to connect to the same db. Making sure you have the credentials right to start will make your code a lot easier to troubleshoot if things don't go right.